# How to start Owasp zap server(exe or jar) from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, owasp, jenkins-cli, zap

Actually, the main issue is if I start the server then my next commond will never trigger as it always running as zap server in listening mode.
Can I run two command line in Jenkins. I have added 2 "Execute Windows batch command" still nothing works. I have added the image in same thread

I have tried by creating a batch file

```
cd /
cd C:\Program Files\OWASP\Zed Attack Proxy
start java -jar zap-2.6.0.jar
```

I am getting error as below after using above batch file

```
Process leaked file descriptors. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors for more information
```

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

I have also use command line arugument directly in "Execute window batch command" like:-

```
java -jar zap-2.6.0.jar
```

But the UI of zap is not starting

I have also tried "`Windows Exe Runner Plugin`"

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Windows+Exe+Runner+Plugin

But jenkins not allowing me to put an exe name in configuration. Looks like a bug of jenkins.

I have also tried by adding zap in environmental variable but that also not working.

Now I am out of idea.

The issue is if I am triggering zap.bat it will do not allow another command to run forward as below which is in my batch:-

[image]

Additionally, UI of zap is not open as it is open after direct clicking on zap.bat file

I have added 2 "Execute Windows batch command" still nothing works

[image]

Any suggestions will be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this issue by creating two jobs in jenkins.
The main job trigger the first job.

Follow the steps :-

1. Go to the configure section of main job
2. Now add "Trigger/call builds on other projects" from Build option
3. Add the project name of zombie job

Note :- uncheck the checkbox of "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds".

Answer (score 2):

Simple - dont start it from the jar!

Start it using the zap.sh or zap.bat scripts we provide as part of the installation :) You'll also probably want to use the -daemon flag.

Or you can use the official ZAP jenkins plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/zap+plugin

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Simon .. but jenkins do not allowing zap to open it's UI, additionlity as first command listing as server .. my further commond on batch is not running.. It like they stack

Comment: I have added the img in question . please have a look

Comment: My jenkins Plug-m manager is not showing any plug as ZAP Plug-in .. is it deprecated or I need to install it by other way?

Comment: It's look like I have to start zap server manually and rest jenkins will take care of..  voting up for daemon thing :)

Comment: Hi Simon.. I am facing an issue regarding zap. The question I have put up here. Please help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727059/apipython-is-not-scanning-slimier-to-manual-attack-in-zap-proxy